# Is there any way to get two relationship arrows from one node A to another node B and node B to node A in neo4j?

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I am using neo4j for developing my application .Suppose there are two nodes ,A and B ,having relationship with properties from A to B and vice versa.In neo4j, relationship is shown by only one arrow with both relationships mentioned on that arrow.I want that there should be two ***separate*** arrows  from node A to B and vice versa mentioning their relationship properties.Is there  any way to get that.![enter image description here][1]Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1) If I understand you correctly, you want something like the following:

```
CREATE (a)-[:r1]->(b)-[:r2]->(a);
```

That creates two nodes that have relationships directed at each other. In this example, the relationships are of type `r1` and `r2`.

2) However, having both relationships might not be necessary, since you can always traverse a relationship in the reverse direction. For example, suppose you created just a single relationship:

```
CREATE (a)-[:r1]->(b);
```

and you wanted to find `a` starting from `b`, you could do this (assuming `b` has the id `1`):

```
START b = node(1)
MATCH (a)-[:r1]->(b)
RETURN a;
```

Comment: Creating relationships between nodes in both ways is not the problem.Problem is ,When I am clicking on that relationship arrow(bidirectional arrow),I am getting information of relationship only from A to B ,not the other one i.e. from B to A on clicking.Suppose,in my case I have a counter on  relationship,which counting the number of users traversing that path.From A to B,it may be 2 and from B to A it may be 1(for e.g).While I am clicking on relationship arrow,it is showing only 1 ,not 2.

Comment: A relationship is always unidirectional, not bidirectional.

Comment: I am agree that relationship is unidirectional.But If we have relationship from A to B and B to A,then its showing one arrow with two relationship showing on it i.e from A to B and B to A.While I am clicking on that arrow,I am getting information about only one relationship i.e from A to B.How I can solve this problem.?

Comment: OK, I understand what is happening. Both arrows are there, but one is *underneath* the other, so you can only click on the one on top. Instead of using the neo4j browser, you can use the neo4j shell, or the console page (http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/), or the webadmin page (http://localhost:7474/webadmin). You won't get the nice graphics, but at least you will see all the results.

Comment: I used above mentioned link,but its showing relationship and their values in tabular form.I want to represent them in graphical manner like in http://localhost:7474/browser/.Is there any to get two arrows,not underneath the other,but separated from each other ?